# what is the standard way to post JSON Object along with file using MultipartEntityBuilder and HTTP Client in Android

Tags: android, json, http-post, apache-httpclient-4.x, multipartentity

I am able to post json object using StringEntity using

httppost.setEntity(newStringEntity(obj.toString()));
HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

but I have to post a file along with json data , I have found many Answers Using  MultipartEntity but it has been deprecated , Please suggest me any tutorial or sample code which uses MultipartEntityBuilder  , thanks
Here is my Code

```
Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {

@Override
public void run() {

JSONObject jsonobject = null;

String requestURL = "URL";

try {

jsonobject = new JSONObject("{\"first\": \"Test\",\"last\": \"User\",\"name\": \"Test 
User\",\"email\": \"tr0121345899@gmail.com\",\"birthdate\": \"1984-01-01\",\"Account\": {\"username\": \"t1r0123425899\",\"password\": \"testuser1234567899\"},\"Address\": {\"postal_code\": \"11230\",\"state_or_province\": \"NY\",\"country\": \"US\"}}");
                } catch (JSONException e1) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }



HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(requestURL);

httppost.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");

httppost.addHeader("X-ConsumerApiClient","0f8f0a024d6344e429f5ee96aa66fbfb5c3973b5");

httppost.addHeader("X-ConsumerApiSignature",

                    "qmt8aEAGRQUvldkDnHw8zgn1kRYuXRDwvmo3TpWlCtE=");

MultipartEntityBuilder multipartEntity = MultipartEntityBuilder.create();
                multipartEntity.setMode(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);

multipartEntity.addPart("file", new FileBody(new
                 File(fileName)));
multipartEntity.addPart("Person", jsonobject.toString());

httppost.setEntity(multipartEntity.build());


try {

     HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

     Log.d("status", "" + response.getStatusLine());

     Log.d("response",EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity()));

    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {

    } catch (IOException e) {


}
}
});

t.start();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the solution,we can split the json object like following and send as a key value

```
  multipartEntity.addPart("data[Asset][file]", new FileBody(file,
                            ContentType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM, "filename.png"));
                    multipartEntity.addTextBody("data[Person][first]", "kk");
                    multipartEntity.addTextBody("data[Person][email]",
                            "rajesh123458@gmail.com");
                    multipartEntity.addTextBody("data[Person][birthdate]",
                            "1984-01-01");
                    multipartEntity.addTextBody("data[Person][Account][username]",
                            "savita123458");
                    multipartEntity.addTextBody("data[Person][Account][password]",
                            "testuser12345678");
        httppost.setEntity(multipartEntity.build());
                    try {
                        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
                        Log.d("status", response.getStatusLine().toString());

                        Log.d("data", EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity()));

                    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace(); // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I have done something similar using http://loopj.com/android-async-http/, which can be used synchronously in your thread

Comment: Thanks for your reply , but I was expecting something else

Answer (score 0):

Try doing this.

```
multipartEntity.addBinaryBody("file", file, ContentType.create("application/octet-stream"), file.getName());
multipartEntity.addTextBody("json", jsonobject.toString(),  ContentType.DEFAULT_BINARY);

httppost.setEntity(multipartEntity.build());
```